# Using char / strings in an F statement

Tags: c++, arduino

Im new to programming. Im using an arduino to send data to my computer (Visual studio c++) and I want to use the data in an if statement.

When I run the code, I can see data coming to my PC. But when I try to use the data in my if statement it doesn't work.

I have tried to convert the data to a char, string and char* 
I'm trying to send (For example) the letter "a"

Can you guys help me?

```
    while (true) {

       std::string test;
       char* sensor = const_cast<char*>(test.c_str());


       arduino.readSerialPort(sensor, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

       std::string value = sensor; 
        cout << value;


        if (value == "a") {
            cout << "if is gemaakt";
        }
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to use array of chars instead of string `test` or at least resize `test` before calling `readSerialPort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for a single char in the begin you have to use `strncmp`:

```
 if (strncmp(value,"a",1) == 0) { // 0 the first char is an a
```

The command strncmp has the following syntax

```
  strncmp(stringToCheck, stringToMatch, numberOfCharsMustMatch) .... Result 0 = match
```